# The createClass helper of babeljs make mangle not working

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

I am using babel as transpiler and I want to mangle some methods with uglifyjs.

Here is a demo:

```
class A {
    methodA() {}
}
```

And its output by babel:

```
var A = function () {
  function A() {
    _classCallCheck(this, A);
  }

  _createClass(A, [{
    key: "methodA",
    value: function methodA() {}
  }]);

  return A;
}();
```

However when I try to mangle `methodA`, it does not work. Because `methodA` in the output is a string.

But the same code output by typescript works, it is not a string:

```
var A = /** @class */ (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.prototype.methodA = function () { };
    return A;
}());
```

So my question is: How can I mangle method name when using babeljs ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer.

Just use `loose` mode:

```
[ ['@babel/preset-env', { loose: true }] ]
```

The result will be closer to TS.